# how to cope with a 10 000 person accessing server in one hour?

Tags: load-testing

I have a share hosting, and I charge 150$/years to host company website. Those websites have a maximum of 2000 person per month accessing the site, mostly WordPress site. So everything is fine until a person in Facebook, with 300 000 friend talk about the website. You know, if just 10% go see the site, it's 30 000 person at the same time accessing the site, and what should append just append, the site crash, and then after 1 hours, it's back on...

So the question, how to cope with that kind of load ?

Comment: Get better hosting

Comment: Look into a dedicated server if you're expecting that kind of traffic. But realistically, who on Facebook, has 300,000 friends? You could implement a proxy server and have multiple servers running in the backend for high-load. This is called "load balancing."

Comment: really popular person have that kind of friend numbers, and today that just append, one post on there wall just kille the server ! And no it's not 300 000 friend, but 281 547

Comment: @ionFish Zynga addicts or celebrities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Scalr http://code.google.com/p/scalr/ and move your hosting to ec2 or RackSpace cloud server you will be able to automatically scale up and down servers as needed based on your server load. Plus it has automatic MySQL redundancy so if any DB crashes it'll bring up a slave as the master.

Comment: what do you think about microsoft azure or grid hosting : http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/gs/ ?